# Whole-house water filter

Tags: water, filter

I have a common type of cylinder filter, about 4x10", that amasses a caramel colored, loose, smooth gunk on the bottom of filter case, as well as coating the outside of the filter itself.  We have treated water, community based, deep well sourced, so all I can guess is that something in the treatment process is precipitating this stuff out.  No particulate matter at all, taste is typical of chlorinated treatment.  Stumped.

Comment: Is the filter exposed to light?

Comment: I'd suggest trying a "spin-down" type filter with a gunk-reservoir and valve before the cartridge to see if that will get some of this where it can be flushed out without changing a filter. And keeping them in the dark to prevent algae growth. Also - you seem to lack an actual question in your question...[edit] to ask one.

Comment: Please post a picture

Comment: Um, it’s a water filter under pressure,,,,exposed to light?!  Also, my "question", I would think, is what is this?